# Delete specified row in Edexcel

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this isn't an appropriate question to ask but I'm looking for any help I can get. 
The "Delete Row" button doesn't seem to be working on an Excel document I'm using.

The code is:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    rownumber = InputBox("What row would you like to delete ?")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
         ws.Rows(86).Delete
    Next ws

    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can anyone see a problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, but it is deleting only the 86th row.
You need to pass the variable `rownumber` to `Rows().Delete` function.

Try this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

rownumber = InputBox("What row would you like to delete ?")
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Rows(rownumber).Delete
Next ws
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is now deleting the specified row. However, it seems to be causing errors for formulae involving the rows below. The "add row" buttton is working well, I've included the code below. Perhaps the "delete row" code needs something similar to change to row numbers? Thanks again.

Comment: For Each ws In Worksheets
rowbefore = rownumber - 1
        ws.Rows(rownumber).Insert
        ws.Rows(rowbefore).Copy ws.Rows(rownumber)
        On Error Resume Next
      ws.Rows(rownumber).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    Next ws

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this macro? Do you want to "delete" the specific row, but keep everything below this row untouched? If so, maybe try to change in my code `ws.Rows(rownumber).Delete` to `ws.Rows(rownumber).ClearContents`, because using Delete method make everything shift up one row.

Comment: Thanks again for you help!

Comment: No problem! Just please mark my answer as "accepted" if you think that it solved your problem :)